# Escaping Quotes with Rails array of hash

Tags: ruby-on-rails

In my rails controller I return a array of hash.

```
@people = [ {name: 'mark' ,age: 25}, {name: 'mary' ,age: 18}]
```

And in my js.erb file I tried the following:

```
console.log("<%= @people %>");
```

Then it's displayed

```
{:name=&gt;&quot;mark&quot;, :age=&gt;25}
```

I tried:

```
@people.to_json
@people.to_json.html_safe
raw @people
j @people #ActionView::Template::Error (undefined method `gsub' for #<Array:0x007f17ed682390>):
```

But none of the solutions worked.

Answer (score 2):

An approach is to convert your ruby Array to json with `.to_json`: It will genereate a **String**. You can, then, pass this string to JavaScript and parse it to a Javascript Object using `JSON.parse`.

<kbd>RUBY ARRAY</kbd> ⇢ `.to_json` ⇢ <kbd>JSON STRING</kbd> ⇢ `JSON.parse`  ⇢ <kbd>JAVASCRIPT OBJECT</kbd>

Something like this in your `.js.erb` file:

```
var myObj = JSON.parse('<%= people.to_json %>');
console.log(myObj);

/*
 or console.log(JSON.parse('<%= people.to_json %>'));
*/
```

---

### EDIT

Testing with a Hash that contains a value with single quote:

```
@people = [ {name: 'ma\'rk' ,age: 25}, {name: 'mary' ,age: 18}]

@people.to_json
#=> "[{\"name\":\"ma'rk\",\"age\":25},{\"name\":\"mary\",\"age\":18}]"
```

In JS:

```
var obj = JSON.parse("[{\"name\":\"ma'rk\",\"age\":25},{\"name\":\"mary\",\"age\":18}]");
console.log(obj); //[Object, Object]
```

Comment: This can further break if the hash contains a value having a single quote.

Comment: @31piy I tested and did not break. But maybe I'm missing something